# Why does this textarea look smaller in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, textarea

Code:

```
  .forms {
   margin-left:99px;
   border: 2px solid #3f3f3f;
   padding-left:5px;
   font-size:20x;
   margin-top:5px;
   color: #666666;
   }

   <textarea rows="5" cols="40" class="forms"></textarea>
```

This looks smaller in Safari and other browsers it looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting font-size to "20px" instead of "20x".